# Json string java bean object

Tags: android, json, gson, jsonobjectrequest

Okay, it's been a year since i touched this code.

I'm using Volley in android to parse the Rest API response. I was really happy with that since GSON made it really easy.

I know this one

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();

User u=gson.fromJson(jsonstring, User.class);
System.out.println("userName: "+u.getusername);
```

But for some reason i find it difficult to make this class and parse.. So for every Bean map i had to pass the specific class and read.

But on the other hand i made generic approach. Were the User.class replaced to all in one Object collection class like the below one.

```
public class Collection {

private Object data;
private CollectionError error;
private int statusCode;
private boolean booleanStatus;


public Object getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(Object data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public CollectionError getError() {
    return error;
}

public void setError(CollectionError error) {
    this.error = error;
}

public int getStatusCode() {
    return statusCode;
}

public void setStatusCode(int statusCode) {
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
}

public boolean isBooleanStatus() {
    return booleanStatus;
}

public void setBooleanStatus(boolean booleanStatus) {
    this.booleanStatus = booleanStatus;
}
```

}

So i pass this to

```
Collection collection = gson.fromJson(jsonstring, CollectionResponse.class);
```

CollcetionResponse is setter and getter class.

So the above was working fine untill, i forget something that made this to work.

When i debug the whole collection was null.

How do i clear this mesh?

Thanks,
Puspharaj

Comment: What do you mean by: "So the above was working fine untill, i forget something that made this to work." ?? Working fine? But not working fine?

Comment: It was working ... All of a sudden I forgot to make it work again